# Angular, mysql and nodejs create a listview

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angularjs

i'm new to angular, the journey is going quite well for now but it's also a bit challenging. Managed to fix some issues with the application like insert dating successfully in the server and so on, but trying to retrieve it inside a listview in angular seems like its not working. Please assist

I am struggling to create a listview using data from nodejs in mysql.

angular is not giving me the data.

index.html:

```
 <div class="message-list">
                        <ul class="message-thread">
                            <li ng-repeat="ppPack in data.pp"
                            >
                                {{data.pp}} Posted by {{data.username}}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

controller

```
$scope.selectFeed = () => {

  

        appService.getFeedList().then( (response) => {
           $scope.$apply(() => {

            let ppPack = {
                fromUserId: document.querySelector(" from_user_id").value,
                post: document.querySelector("#post").value
            }
                
            });

            $scope.data.pp = response.pp;


        }).catch( (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            alert('Unexpected Error, Try go back and redo somethings you did!.');
        });

}
```

helper class

```
async getFeedList(){
        try {
            return await this.db.query(
                `SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id ASC`,
                [params.from_user_id,params.posts]
            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn(error);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

service class

```
 getFeedList() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.httpCall({
                url: '/getPosts',
                'posts': $scope.data.pp,
                'from_user_id': $scope.data.username
            }).then((response) => {
                resolve(response);
            }).catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-repeat uses the value that you pass to the dom.

Starting with your helper class, you need to pass out the value in which you want to collect from the db, even though it seems like you query everything, giving params value to them will make it easier for you to understand the logic of the code, which means you query should be:

```
async getFeedList(posts, from_user_id)){  
      try {
       return await this.db.query(
       `SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id ASC`,
          [params.from_user_id,params.posts]
            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn(error);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And in your service class, also pass the params

```
 getFeedList(posts, from_user_id) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.httpCall({
                url: '/getPosts',
                'posts': posts,
                'from_user_id': from_user_id
            }).then((response) => {
                resolve(response);
            }).catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    }
```

and in your controller file should be outside other scopes since they won't be called out unless they requesting the service on their own like this:

```
 appService.getFeedList()
    .then((response) => {
      $scope.$apply(() => {
        $scope.postsData = response.postsData;
      //output to see the array before commit to the scope  
console.log(response);
      });
         })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
          alert("error code!.");
             });
```

and then finally in your home.html you can call

```
     <div class="list-group">
        <ul class="list-group-item"
           ng-repeat="post in postsData"> 
            {{post.post}} Posted by <strong>{{post.from_user_id}} </strong</ul>
              </div>
```

Some best practise tips from the official angular site:

[Best Practice: If you are working with objects that have a unique identifier property, you should track by this identifier instead of the object instance, e.g. item in items track by item.id. Should you reload your data later, ngRepeat will not have to rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones. For large collections, this significantly improves rendering performance.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: wow thank you so much. I was struggling to understand I was doing wrong for weeks now. I was just implement the change and understand your previous code on the (NULL,NULL) issue and now easy and straight forward explanation on what to do. Thank you @Lucien

Comment: I have been refreshing this page everyday until someone who help kind me then boom